# How to set PYTHONPATH on web server

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I have been running Apache and PHP successfully for a while and would now like to use python as well. I have installed django and mod_wsgi, but still haven't got them working.

I get errors like

```
ImportError: Could not import settings '/srv/django_projects/proj1/settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?):
```

in my apache logs. Tutorials about setting PYTHONPATH seem to require adding an export command to webserver startup scripts, but frankly I have no idea what I'm doing so I'd like to get some clarity about what's going on, and what I should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a virtual environment as documented in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

Also see:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath

and the python-path option of:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess

Which of the latter you might use depends on how you are running mod_wsgi.

So, lots of documentation available.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will check it out. It amazing how much documentation there is, and yet how little of it gives you a decent overview without largely useless interjections.